# CSS dropdown menus no working

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create dropdown navigation menu.

Every article and video I've found shows the same thing that I'm doing but it can't seem to get it right.

There should be a dropdown for the Systems and Forms items.
I know I can use CSS classes as another option but I want to get working this way.

The HTML and CSS for the page is below.

```css
#MenuBar {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#MenuBar ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

#MenuBar ul a {
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  line-height: 32px;
}

#MenuBar ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

#MenuBar ul li:hover {
  background: #f6f6;
}


/*Dropdown menus*/

#MenuBar ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

#MenuBar ul ul li {
  width: 150px;
}

#MenuBar ul ul a {
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}


/*Dropdown menu items*/

#MenuBar ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="MenuBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Systems</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Payroll</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Forms</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">IT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">HR</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Facilities</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: So what is your question here?

Comment: @coockoo the menu isn't shown

Comment: @coockoo `li` doesn't seem

Comment: your markup is not right. put dropdown ul in li tag

Comment: @Ray see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Just insert the `ul` of child inside `li` of parent...
for `float` to left use `padding-left: 0px;`

```css
          #MenuBar{
              margin-top:15px;
          }

          #MenuBar ul{
              list-style:none;
              float:left;
          }

          #MenuBar ul a{
              display:block;
              color:#333;
              text-decoration:none;
              padding:0px 15px;
              line-height:32px;
          }

          #MenuBar ul li{
              position:relative;
              float:left;
          }

          #MenuBar ul li:hover{
              background:#f6f6;
          }
  #MenuBar ul li:hover ul{
              display:block;
          }
          /*Dropdown menus*/
          #MenuBar ul ul{
              display: none;
              position:absolute;
          }
          #MenuBar ul ul li{
              width:150px;
          }

          #MenuBar ul ul a{
              line-height:120%;
              padding: 10px 15px;
          }
          /*Dropdown menu items*/
          #MenuBar ul li:hover  ul{
              display:block;
              padding-left: 0px;
              }
```

```html
              <nav id="MenuBar">
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Systems</a></li>
                          <ul>
                              <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Payroll</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
                          </ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Forms</a>
                          <ul>
                              <li><a href="#">IT</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">HR</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Facilities</a></li>
                          </ul>
                          </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </nav>
```

Comment: Tell me for more help

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `dropdown` `ul` inside the parent `li` like this

```css
#MenuBar{
              margin-top:15px;
          }

          #MenuBar ul{
              list-style:none;
              float:left;
          }

          #MenuBar ul a{
              display:block;
              color:#333;
              text-decoration:none;
              padding:0px 15px;
              line-height:32px;
          }

          #MenuBar ul li{
              position:relative;
              float:left;
          }

          #MenuBar ul li:hover{
              background:#f6f6;
          }

          /*Dropdown menus*/
          #MenuBar ul ul{
              display: none;
              position:absolute;
              top: 100%;
              left: 0;
          }
          #MenuBar ul ul li{
              width:150px;
          }

          #MenuBar ul ul a{
              line-height:120%;
              padding: 10px 15px;
          }
          /*Dropdown menu items*/
          #MenuBar ul li:hover ul{
              display:block;
              }
```

```html
<nav id="MenuBar">
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Systems</a>
                          <ul>
                              <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Payroll</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
                          </ul>
                       </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Forms</a>
                          <ul>
                              <li><a href="#">IT</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">HR</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Facilities</a></li>
                          </ul>
                       </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </nav>
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nu1ykvha/)